# gitlab SSH key project cloning issue

Tags: git, ssh, clone, gitlab, ssh-keys

I am very new to using GIT. I know the basics of adding, committing, pushing and pulling.

My teams project is stored on gitlab. I set up my public SSH key at work in order for us to work together on the project.
We were trying to work from home so I am setting up another SSH key, I can clone the project. I set up the SSH key correctly (I made sure of this... it says I have two SSH keys stored on gitlab) but I am getting this message when I run the `git clone` command... I have full access to the repository... I am listed as owner.
I am thinking maybe there is an issue with my mac. Maybe I haven't configured something?

```
ryans-imac:~ ryanchampin$ git clone git@gitlab.synapseny.com:acr-booth.git
Cloning into ‘acr-booth’…
ssh: connect to host gitlab.synapseny.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: What does `ssh git@gitlab.synapseny.com` return? Does it work? If not, what does `ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.synapseny.com` return?

Comment: ok so for ssh git@gitlab.synapseny.com......this doesnt do anything but basically freeze my terminal lol...the second one gives me this:     ryans-imac:~ ryanchampin$ ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.synapseny.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.synapseny.com [66.179.230.168] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 66.179.230.168 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host gitlab.synapseny.com port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: timeout? You can try http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/86646 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if your GitLab server has been successfully configured by running this command from the installation directory: `bundle exec rake gitlab:check`

Next, you should try to setup `gitlab-shell` by running this command: `bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:setup`